# How to Insert a line after a pattern and insert another line before the first occurence of a word from pattern1 using sed?

Tags: perl, sed

```
sub tc1 {
a
b
c
d
endcase
}
sub tc2
{
a
b
c
endcase
}
```

I want to call a subroutine say start() after sub tc1 and call stop() before that endcase of sub tc1

I used this command

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(sub\s+TC1[\s\n]+\{)(.*)endcase/$1\n&start();$2&stop();\nendcase/smg' file.txt
```

### Output

```
sub tc1 {
&start();
a
b
c
d
endcase
}
sub tc2
{
a
b
c
stop();
endcase
}
```

but it is modifying at lastly matched endcase pattern

### Expected output

```
sub tc1 {
&start();
a
b
c
d
&stop();
endcase
}
```

Comment: Not clear, please do explain the logic behind the expected output.

Comment: I want to append a line start(); after the pattern /sub tc1/ and prepend a line stop(); before the first occurence of the pattern /endcase/ after /sub tc1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy task of `awk`, could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk '
/sub tc1/{
  sub_tcl_val=$0 ORS "&start();"
  flag=val=""
  next
}
/endcase/ && ++count==1{
  flag=1
  print sub_tcl_val ORS val ORS "&stop()" ORS $0 ORS "}"
  val=sub_tcl_val=""
  next
}
!flag{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
sub tc1 {
&start();
a
b
c
d
&stop()
endcase
}
```

Comment: But if I have lines before sub tc1 it is appending those lines after start();

Comment: @Sasi, I have edited it now, could you please check now and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/sub tc1/,/endcase/!b;/sub tc1/a\&start();' -e '/endcase/i\&stop();' file
```

Use a range to focus on the start/end delimiters in this case `sub tc1`/`endcase`. Then append the string `&start();` after the start delimiter and insert the string `&stop();` before the end delimiter.

Comment: $ sed -e '/sub tc1/,/endcase/!b;/sub tc1/a\&start();' -e '/endcase/i\&stop();' myfil
sed -e '/sub tc1/,/endcase/bvi;/sub tc1/a\&start();' -e '/endcase/i\&stop();' myfil
sed: can't find label for jump to `vi'

Comment: @sasi  your input seems some what garbled. Try removing everything following the first occurrence  of `myfil`.